# Insert New record id to url

Tags: php

Get the last record id inserted to db and pass to redirect url

my url is employeesview.php?showdetail=&id=

so id mus go after &id=

thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? We are here to help you solve problems you run into during the process, not to write the code for you.

Comment: And what is your database structure? Are the ids created by auto_increment?

Answer (score 0):

Question could be improved (e.g. what DB to be used, why do you think you have to provide the ID as HTTP GET argument, etc.)

But the answer could be easy. Just guessing you are using a mysql db (because php beginners often use mysql).. in this case please check auto_increment attribute for your ID column in sql. It allows that PHP automatically uses the next ID for your new records, and you don't need to provide the ID for inserting a new row.

See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp